# Ошибка запроса в jquery ajax в Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Отправляю запрос в базу, кликаю на кнопку сохранить отрабатывает beforeSend лоадер, и запись в базу доходит и записывается, но сам ajax возвращает error, следовательно success не выполняется. Данные в базу пишутся. В чем может быть проблема?????

```
    $('#form_update').on('click', '#button_update', function(){

   var category = $('input#category_edit').val();
   var is_active = $('select#status').val();
   var title = $('input#title').val();
   var description = $('textarea#description').val();

 var status;
   if(is_active == 1) {
      status = "Отключено";
   }else{
      status ="Включено";
   }

   $.ajax({
     url: "/admin/categories/update",
     type: "post",
     beforeSend: function(){
        var bodyH = $(window).height() / 2;
        $("div#edit_cat").after('<div id="system-load" style="position:fixed;'
        + 'top:0px; left:600px; width:10%; height:10%;'
        + 'z-index:99999999; color:#fff; padding-top:' + bodyH + 'px;"'
        + 'align="center">'
        + '<img src="/images/preloader.gif"'
        + ' alt="Пожалуйста, подождите..." /></div>');
        $(window).bind('load', function() {
        $('#system-loading').fadeOut('slow').remove();
        $('#sytem-content').animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast');
});
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
       'id':item_id,
       '_token':csrf,
       'category':category,
       'is_active':is_active,
       'title':title,
       'description':description,
     },
     succces: function(data){
          alert("Ajax запрос выполнен\n"+data.message);
          $("tr#"+item_id+"> td[class=cat]").text(category);
          $("tr#"+item_id+"> td[class=status]").text(status);
          $("#system-load").remove();
        },
     error: function(xhr,status,error){
       alert('Ошибка Ajax-запроса\n'+status+'\n'+error);
          console.log(status);
          console.log(error);
     }
   });
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в консоль. Что у вас возвращает запрос то?

Comment: алертом выводит - unexpected end of json input

Comment: судя по скрину - http://prntscr.com/e91fbd , запрос идет нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть в `$.ajax()` параметр `dataType: 'json'`. Вот что о нем написано [в документации](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>  The type of data that you're expecting **back from the
>   server**. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

То есть, если вы указали json, то и вернуть должны строго его. Вы же, судя по всему, считаете, что этот параметр обозначает не то, что сервер должен вернуть, а то, что вы ему передаете. Но это не так :)

Ну и еще, надо писать не `succces`, а `succcess`.

Comment: убрал. В скрипте ничего не возвращаю:    public function update(Request $request)
    {    
        sleep(1);
        $category = Category::find($request->input("id"));
        $category->update($request->except('_token'));
    }

Comment: И что в итоге в консоли видно в браузере?

Comment: Пример работы можно увидеть тут - https://goo.gl/moxqSl . При клике на кнопку править аякс подгружает описание категории. А вот при клике на сохранить все зависает и алерты success так и не выводятся.

Comment: Ошибок не не выдает

Comment: А в каком скрипте код-то смотреть? Их там штук 30 )

Comment: то все от шаблона, мой файл называется так - edit_cat.js

Comment: @Alkos обновил ответ )